# Dotnet test results html output file hosting via IIS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, ui-automation, dotnet-test

I am currently working on C# selenium automation tests. My setup is simple: running tests on a test server (accessible via remote desktop), I've setup task scheduler trigger to run them every day via this command:
`dotnet test --logger:"html;LogFileName=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\TestResults\TestResults.html" C:\AutomationSuite\Testsuite.dll`

The test results output file is stored in a wwwroot foolder and is uploaded to a website that is accessible via vpn.
Visible output:[image]

Now, my question is: are there any extensions or convertors for my test results to be more appealing to the eye? Like in a pie chart or something like that (running on azure devops the output of test run is more appealing).

Is it possible or am I digging too deep?
Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to set it up using AllureReport